# visualbasic 2012 data filtering

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am making a data management program with visual basic 2012 as frontend and MySQL as backend. I want to filter a data grid view table with a List box (multiple selections). When I select one item it works fine and when I select multiple items in the List box, I do not have code. I am able to get all the items of a column in the list box by following code:

```
Query = "Select * from `rrrr.data`.`trial` "
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
While READER.Read
    Dim sCountry = READER.GetString("COUNTRY")
                   ListBox1.Items.Add(sCountry)
    End While
```

But for filtering data when I use below query it does not work ( for  multiple selected  or more than one item ) It does not work. The query which I use is:

```
Query = "Select * from `rrrr.data`.`trial` Where  `COUNTRY`in  ('" & ListBox1.SelectedItem& "'  )"
```

Kindly help me out
Also can I use  `Combobox` and Checked List Box for similar filtering.